# I left my debit card unattended -- how exposed am I?

Tags: credit-card, risk

I yesterday visited a restaurant I usually visit, but it seems that after paying with my debit card, I accidentally left it there. Today (almost 24 hours later) I had realized that I didn't have it with me anymore.

I am not really that concerned about the unauthorized use of the card, since my previous experience with this bank (Bank of America) resulted in them cancelling any unauthorized payment first and asking questions later.

However, I'm concerned about what I don't know: what are the risks of leaving it unattended for a while?

[This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62002/how-much-information-is-released-when-paying-with-a-debit-card) pointed on the fact that asking for the zip code plays the extra role of verifying the actual owner -- but this restaurant never required me to indicate my zip code in order to pay them.

Risks that come to mind but I'd like someone to help solidify by explaining on how this may contribute are:

- identity theft
- unauthorized payments (card theft)
- hacking other services that check on the last 4 digits of the card
- anything else I may have missed?

Sidenote: I rarely contribute but read on this StackExchange site and find it awesomely helpful. If anyone has suggestions on how to make this question helpful to others (maybe making it broader?), please go ahead and provide your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you card can be misused at various places. Though, it has never happened to me, I believe there are some websites which accept payments from debit cards without any secure 3D password. All they ask for is CVV and Card#.

I would suggest you to block it right away.

Comment: 3D Secure is incredibly uncommon with US e-commerce merchants